# How to? Creating Redux selectors with arguments

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

I have a state with a map array of some data.
I need to select one object from it.
I can get the whole array using

```
function mapStateToProps (state) {
  return {
    allDataSet: state.data
  }
}
```

and then select the entity needed placing logic in the component. Like this:

```
(id) => this.props.allDataSet.filter((entity) => entity.id === id)
```

But somehow I believe that doing this is wrong and against all of the best practices, as all selectors logic should be separated from the component. 

Exactly this case is simple, but i real project I had to place complex selectors inside my component just to get data by Id...
Is there any patterns or best practices that provides solution for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should normalize allDataSet as an object and the keys should be the id of the entity.

```
function mapStateToProps (state) {
  let allDataSet = {};
  state.data.forEach((datum) => {
    allDataSet[datum.id] = datum;
  })
  return {
    allDataSet
  }
}
```

Then you can access the needed entity just by `this.props.allDataSet[id]`

Take a look at this
http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/reducers/NormalizingStateShape.html

Comment: Wow.
I was already aware about normalization and even had a look at normalizr library, but still those two chunks of information was not connected in my weak brain. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can keep your logic inside `mapStateToProps`

```
function mapStateToProps (state) {
  return {
    entity: state.data.filter((entity) => entity.id === state.selecetedId)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want your selector to be reusable, then you can define it in a separate file:

```
export function getSelectedEntity(state) {
  return state.data.filter((entity) => entity.id === state.selectedId)
}
```

Then import and call the selector function in your `mapStateToProps()`:

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    entity: getSelectedEntity(state)
  };
}
```

One advantage of this pattern is that you can easily write a unit test for the selector, since it is a pure function and is kept separate from your React component.

Consider using [Reselect](https://github.com/reactjs/reselect), which is a helper library for creating memoized selector functions.

Comment: Thanks! Following this pattern for some time. Just wanted to simplify the example, so skipped this pattern.